# Consuming a web page through my blackberry app

Tags: web-services, blackberry, browser

I want to open a web page and then take certain contents from this page onto some array elements and then work on it . I am able to open the page in a new browser but how do i read it . Does it have any inputbuffer's or something like in android . plss i need help ... just migrated from android .

Comment: if you are using webservice then you have to use ksoap2 jar and have to parse xml into string

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to open InputStream instance:

```
String someAddress = "http://www.myserver.com/mypage.html";  
HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(someAddress);
InputStream inputStream = httpConnection.openInputStream();
```

After that use built InputStream instance to process contents of received web-page.